# Encapsulating a 1D array field with a 2D array property in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, properties

I have a class that contains a public 2D array as a part of its interface:

```
public Vector2Int MazeSize { get; }
public MazeCellDescriptor[,] wallGrid { get; }
```

I need to serialize this class, and the serializer that we are using can't handle multidimensional arrays* (oops!)

I could create a function to access the array elements...

```
    public Vector2Int MazeSize { get; }
    private MazeCellDescriptor[] wallGrid;
    public MazeCellDescriptor getWall (int x, int y) => this.wallGrid[x + (y * this.MazeSize.x)];
```

... but it would break my existing interface. Ideally, I would just define a 2D array property and convert it to a 1D array on the backside, no need to change the public interface. This seems like the most OOO solution, but I'm not sure if it's possible and I'm just getting the syntax wrong, or if there's no way to do this.

```
public MazeCellDescriptor[int x, int y] WallGrid => this.wallGrid[x + (y * this.MazeSize.x)];
public MazeCellDescriptor[,] WallGrid[int x, int y] => this.wallGrid[x + (y * this.MazeSize.x)];
// or something like that, neither of these compile...
```

*For context, this is a Unity game project. I found a few possible solutions (changing the interface, or [converting the array before serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58559529/serializing-a-2d-array-with-jsonutility)), so I'm not looking for general advice, just wondering if this specific approach is possible in the language I use. Thank you!

Comment: You could add a new type with an indexer property; `public T this[int x, int y] { get => ...; set => ...; }` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you tried was almost there. You could simply use a property like e.g.

```
public MazeCellDescriptor this[int x, int y]
{
    get => this.wallGrid[x + (y * this.MazeSize.x)];
    set
    {
        this.wallGrid[x + (y * this.MazeSize.x)] = value;
    }
}
```